# Laravel Token Signature could not be verified

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel/Lumen as an API for the backend of a webapp and run into a hiccup.

In an example I have a route that does not need the user to be authenticated. But I do want to check in the routes controller *if* the user visiting has a valid token.

So I wrote the following:

```
    if ($tokenFetch = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
        $token = str_replace("Bearer ", "", $request->header('Authorization'));
    } else {
        $token = '';
    }
```

I believe the above will check the Bearer token is valid else it will return a blank variable.

**The following is my entire Controller.**

```
public function show($url, Request $request)
    {

        if ($tokenFetch = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            $token = str_replace("Bearer ", "", $request->header('Authorization'));
        } else {
            $token = 'book';
        }
        return response()->json(['token' => $token]);
    }
```

**The Problem**

If I a pass in a valid Token Bearer, it returns the token **but** if I pass in an invalid one I get the following error:

> TokenInvalidException in NamshiAdapter.php line 62:
>
> Token Signature could not be verified.

If I don't pass a token at all:

> JWTException in JWTAuth.php line 195:
>
> The token could not be parsed from the request

Is there a way to check if a token is passed and if it has then check if its valid, but also if one has not been passed then return a blank return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap it inside try/catch block

```
public function show($url, Request $request)
{
    try {
        $tokenFetch = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) 
        $token = str_replace("Bearer ", "", $request->header('Authorization'));
    }catch(\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e){//general JWT exception
        $token = 'book';
    }
    return response()->json(['token' => $token]);
}
```

> There are few exceptions that you might want to handle separately ([jwt-auth/Exceptions](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/tree/develop/src/Exceptions))

Also as you're using laravel 5 you can global handling for JWT exceptions ,not recommended in this case but you should know of this option and choose yourself. `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` and inside `render` method add [at the top]

```
if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException) {
    //what happen when JWT exception occurs
}
```

Comment: This still flags up `$tokenFetch = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) ` that it cannot parse

Comment: explain ? the first code I gave you will return `book` in token if error occurred [didn't pass token/invalid/something went wrong] other wise [everything went ok] it will return `str_replace("Bearer ", "", $request->header('Authorization'));` as token

Comment: Gal I think that your solution is totally legitimate. The only reason I didn't propose by myself it was because in the question it was specifically said "check"  which it's not the best solution btw.So +1!

Comment: @borracciaBlu He could create a check method but this would just be rewriting parts of plugin and when the plugin code will change this might not work well.[According to the docs](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication#retreiving-the-authenticated-user-from-a-token) if an exception wasn't thrown then the token is valid.

Comment: @gal When running it.

>TokenInvalidException in NamshiAdapter.php line 63:
>Token Signature could not be verified.

Comment: Sorry I meant Line 62 not 63

Comment: I have edited the code although it should've worked before ,if it still doesn't run it with debugger as you might get this error from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to achieve what you want.

#### Check if a token is passed:

If you check in the documentation of [parseToken](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/master/src/JWTAuth.php#L191) you'll see that the algorithm to check if we pass a token is:

```
if (! $token = $this->parseAuthHeader($header, $method)) {
    if (! $token = $this->request->query($query, false)) {
    }
}


// which it will be in your case:
$hasToken = true;

$header = $request->headers->get('authorization');
if (! starts_with(strtolower('authorization'), 'bearer')) {
    if (! $request->query('token', false)) {
        $hasToken = false;
    }
}
```

#### Check if a token is valid:

Please note that the NamshiAdapter use the `Namshi\JOSE` package so read the documentation [here](https://github.com/namshi/jose).

In [NamshiAdapter.php](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/e84944be04353f9c94a20dde67097521c05fb87d/src/Providers/JWT/Namshi.php#L75) as you can see the line who rise your error are:

```
if (! $jws->verify($this->secret, $this->algo)) {
    throw new TokenInvalidException('Token Signature could not be verified.');
}

// in your case:
// + try to var_dump $this->secret, $this->algo
// + use Namshi\JOSE\JWS

// if you var_dump
$jsw = new JWS(['typ' => 'JWT', 'alg' => $algo]);
$jws = $this->jws->load($token, false);

// if you want to follow the documentation of Namshi\JOSE
$jws = JWS::load($tokenString, false, $encoder, 'SecLib');

// again var_dump for $this->secret, $this->algo
$isValidToken = ($jws->verify($this->secret, $this->algo));
```

Comment: The application fails on parseAuthHeader()

Comment: You have to use the second part of the code parseAuthHeader is just to explain you where I took the code... You have to start from $hasToken

Comment: Where is the second part of the code going? Is it replacing the original if in NamshiAdapter?