# Laravel 5.4 JWT - Token Signature could not be verified

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I'm building an `api` to authenticate my users through my mobile application
The login controller return me the correct `token`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Api\V1\Controllers;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Api\V1\Requests\LoginRequest;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(LoginRequest $request, JWTAuth $JWTAuth)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only(['username', 'password']);

        try {
            $token = $JWTAuth->attempt($credentials);

            if(!$token) {
                throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
            }

        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            throw new HttpException(500);
        }

        return response()
            ->json([
                'status' => 'ok',
                'token' => $token
            ]);
    }
}
```

Postman result

```
{
  "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC9iZXRhZmlsZS5vcmdcL2dpcHNcL3B1YmxpY1wvYXBpXC9hdXRoXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTQ5Mjc4MDI2NiwiZXhwIjoxNDkyNzgzODY2LCJuYmYiOjE0OTI3ODAyNjYsImp0aSI6InZHWkxaNHNqRUlqYW05WTMifQ.g8_-qHsVVvCEj9_BoqDCKJ9QHvm-yqWALsXmxeMK_3c"
}
```

Now when I tried to get the current user by token I get the signature error
User controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Api\V1\Controllers;

use JWTAuth;
use App\Record;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Helpers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class RecordController extends Controller
{
    use Helpers;

    public function store(Request $request) {
        //$record = new Record;
        //return $this->currentUser();
        $currentUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        return $currentUser;

    }

    private function currentUser() {
        return JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    }
}
```

Postman result

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Token Signature could not be verified.",
    "status_code": 500
  }
}
```

I already try by pass the token by url `domain.com/api/auth?token=token_key` and by header Authorization Bearer token_key

Also I have the jwt secret inside `config/jwt.php 'secret' => env('jwt_secret')` and inside `.env JWT_SECRET=jwt_secret`

Any tip to help to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: have you registered these `'jwt.auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken',
    'jwt.refresh' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken',` to your middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Comment: @AmrAly yes I have this lines inside kernel.php

Comment: also you need to add `Authorization: Bearer add_your_token_here` in your header as `key : value` in postman while sending the request

Comment: Hi I tried this too and also by passing the token directly on url

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872446/laravel-token-signature-could-not-be-verified) out

Comment: Fix it, I don't now why but after generate a new app key the jwt auth starts work properly.
`php artisan key:generate`

Many thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Try generate a key:

```
php artisan jwt:secret
```

This will update your `.env` file with something like `JWT_SECRET=foobar`